# Check if a value from session is null in gatling

Tags: java, gatling

how can I check whether a value is present in the response and save it in that case? Also, I am trying to check if an optional value from session is null in gatling before doing the get, but I am getting a problem when doing the doIf, this is my code:

```
    builder
  .doWhile("${scrollId.exists()}") {
    exec(http(s"$title")
      .post(endpoint)
      .headers(headers)
      .body(ElFileBody(requestBodyFilePath))
      .check(jsonPath("$.scrollId").saveAs("scrollId")) //how can I check if exists before saving it?
      .check(status.is(200)))
      .pause(1)
      //save value from response
      .exec(session => {
        //.doIf(session("scrollId").asOption[String].isEmpty) here is the problem
      val scrollId = session("scrollId").asOption[String].get
      session.set("scrollId", scrollId)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session("scrollId").asOption[String].isDefined
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).